# Autologin to sites that don't have "remember me" feature

Tags: firefox, passwords, auto-login

There's one site that I have to visit quite often that doesn't have a "remember me" checkbox. Is there some extension for Firefox that maybe can automatically execute some actions (or some JavaScript) when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

[Autofill by tohodo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-quantum/)

I tried its chrome variant and it works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to autoclick the login button with execution of the following JS with Autofill: `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.innerHTML = "$(\"#<button name>\").click()"; document.body.appendChild(script);`